# Deploy solution which includes external projects

Tags: appharbor

My project have the references to the bunch of projects from another solution (this solution also linked to own Git repository), but for convinience (to be able debug and modify them from one solution) I include these projects to my web-project solution which I want to deploy on AppHarbor. Maybe it could be said that these are sub-modules of my solution. But now I can't figure out proper way to deploy the solution on AppHarbor.
More structured description:
--Solution

------DeployedProject

------[SolutionFolderForExternalProjects]

---------Proj1ReferencedFromDeployedProject

----------Proj2ReferencedFromDeployedProject

Solution - linked to repo1
Proj1 and Proj2 - also belong external solution which linked to repo2, still ADDED to the repo1 explecitly -
git add SolutionFolderForExternalProjects/

How I should handle this sort of deployment?

Answer (score 1):

AppHarbor really needs all dependencies pushed for us to successfully build you project. Generally, having one solution reference projects in some other random location on your local drive and checked into a different repository is probably not an optimal model. It's also bound to cause problems if some other person has to check out and build your code.

You should consider either combining the two solution structures into one repository (you can still have multiple solution files, see the [AppHarbor solution file convention](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention)). Alternatively, package the respective dependencies up as NuGet packages and include them in your project using NuGet.